# Select a Tag with a Selector from a Text Variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have a string which contains text and some `<a>` tags in it; I want to know how I can select a tag from the variable and loop it. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
var text = `some string here with <a href="#link">http:something.com</a> more string and more links also`;

$('a', text).each(function() {

            var string = $(this).html();
            $(this).html(string.substring(0, length-1)+(string.length > length ? end : ''));

        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the text in a div (or other element) then `find()` it:

```
var text = 'some string here with <a href="#link">http:something.com</a> more string and more links also';

text = $('<div>' + text + '</div>');

text.find('a').each(function() {
    var length = 10;
    var end = '...';

    var string = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(string.substring(0, length) + (string.length > length ? end : ''));
});

var text = text.html();

// Put it into a textarea
$('#myTextarea').val(text);
```

Comment: greg thank you for answering and its working, but only one problem left is.. how can i change the text init and assign it back at same position as it was before?

Comment: The code you have is pretty much working if you define length and end. You just need to grab `text.html()` after you run it.

Comment: nope, text.html() is not working, my row loops gets ended when i run this text.html(), it wont run anymore javascript after it and wont show any error eaither in firebug.

Comment: solved: (ofcourse with greg tips (: ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553784/jquery-each-loop-and-replace-to-same-location/1554094#1554094

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('a', text).each(function() {
```

with

```
$(text, 'a').each(function() {
```

and see if it works.

Comment: your selector also worked, but it gave problem on $(this).html('adding new value');

btw do you know how i can put same value in text variable after changing it?