# jquery .each loop and replace to same location?

Tags: jquery, replace, css-selectors, selector

i got help ([Select a Tag with a Selector from a Text Variable using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553601/jquery-select-a-tag-with-selector-from-a-text-veriable)) on looping the static var and replacing it value, but just one question is left from it, is how can i replace finded tags  with newly changed tags in the text area

Code:

```
var length = 30;
var end    = '...';
var text = `some string here with <a href="#link">http:something.com</a> more string and more links also`;

$('<div>' + text + '</div>').find('a').each(function() {

                var link_value = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(link_value.substring(0, length-1)+(link_value.length > length ? end : ''));
// now how can i put $(this).html() back in the text area, which it was found at?

        });
```

Comment: its define above and so is end var :)

Comment: I've edited my answer in the previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var length = 30;
    var end    = '...';
    var div = $('<div>' + text + '</div>');
    $(div).find('a').each(function() {
        var link_value = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(link_value.substring(0, length)+(link_value.length > length ? end : ''));
    });

    var text = div.html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when changing this one way or the other, the changes are made and you don't need to put it back instead just use end()

```
var div = $('<div>' + text + '</div>').find('a').each(function() {...}).end();
```

Comment: hmmm.. i will try later on sometime, to see if it works. but thanks for the response :)